# Алгоритм синхронизации списка файлов на диске и в БД

Tags: алгоритм

При старте приложения будет отображаться список папок, в папках файлы. Сам процесс сканирования этих папок занимает немного времени, поэтому решил сохранять названия и пути в этим файлам и папкам в базе данных. После чего процесс запуска значительно ускорился. Но как быть, если пользователь решит удалить/изменить или добавить папку или файл. Так же необходимо сохранить порядок фалов как на устройстве. Как бы вы решили данный вопрос?

Comment: Для отслеживания удаления/добавления в некоторых языках есть событийная модель. А при сканировании устройства файлы будут обрабатываться в таком же порядке, в котором они и расположены, а уж потом пользователь выбирает, в каком порядке отобрадать их

Comment: "сохранить порядок фалов как на устройстве" - а какой порядок на устройстве и какой он у вас сейчас? Добавте в вопрос код, где вы читаете файлы и добавляете в БД.

Comment: Приложение будет на JAVA для Android.  Представьте, есть 3 файла - file1, file2, file3. Приложение записало их в базу данных. Потом пользователь удалил file3 и добавил file 4. Какой должен быть алгоритм, что бы удалить file3 из базы данных и записать file4? Получается надо перебирать список в списке?

Comment: Порядок файлов на устройстве это как? Как вы собираетесь его определить? На совсем старых системах с прямым доступом к телу диска или ленты еще можно было извращаться и то не всегда, да и не нужно. За расположение файлов на носителе отвечает файловая система, которая просто отдает вам список файлов, а в каком порядке вы будете отображать их имена - ваше дело, файловой системы и, тем более, устройства это не касается. Так что вашу задачу можно свести к синхронизации данных файловой системы и БД.

Answer (score 1):

Ну алгоритм так алгоритм.

1. Получаем список файлов из файловой системы `FSFiles`, сортируем в алфавитном порядке
2. Получаем список файлов из базы данных `DBFiles`, отсортированный в алфавитном порядке
3. Допустим получили что-то такое:

   ```
   N | FSFiles | DBFiles  
   --|---------|--------  
   1 | file1   | file1  
   2 | file2   | file3
   3 | file4   | file4
   ```

   В одном цикле с двумя счетчиками просматриваем списки до тех пор, пока оба счетчика не дойдут до конца.

   3.1. Если `FSFiles[i] = DBFiles[j]`, то увеличиваем оба счетчика на единицу и повторяем, иначе 3.2.
   3.2. Если `FSFiles[i] < DBFiles[j]` (алфавитное сравнение), то добавляем `FSFiles[i]` в БД, увеличиваем `i` и возвращаемся в 3.1., иначе 3.3.
   3.3. Если `FSFiles[i] > DBFiles[j]`, то удаляем `DBFiles[j]` из БД, увеличиваем `j` и возвращаемся в 3.1.
   Если в процессе просмотра один из счетчиков уже дошел до конца списка файлов, то либо дописываем оставшиеся в `FSFiles` записи в БД, либо удаляем из БД все, что осталось в `DBFiles`, в зависимости от того, кто из них быстрее закончился.

Сложность алгоритма (без учета предварительной сортировки списков) линейная, пропорциональна длине `FSFiles U DBFiles`.

В некоторых системах предусмотрена возможность слушать события мониторинга файловой системы (например аудит объектов ФС в Windows, правда больно тяжелый и журналы логов быстро забивает, но есть)

Некоторые библиотеки и фреймворки позволяют создавать и использовать собственный (не системный) мониторинг (например FileSystemWatcher в классическом .NET, к системному аудиту отношения не имеет, но, естественно, слушает те же самые события Win API, что и аудит, только логи не захламляет).

Если есть возможность использовать любой вид событийного мониторинга, то его можно использовать как основной источник данных об изменениях, а описанный выше алгоритм запускать с небольшой периодичностью для корректировки "промахов" мониторинга, которые гарантированно будут при интенсивной работе с файлами.